# How to determine if elements.parentNode or Ancestor has class?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of inputs that make up my UI that I'm using to build a json file. In my json file, I have 2 scopes, and each input will add a different string to either scope. For the example, the 2 objects I'd like to prepare to append to are `three-obj` and `three-array`. If an `input.parentNode` contains the either of those classes, I'd like to push it to the correct object.

To do this, I started by getting all my inputs into an `NodeList` using `querySelectorAll`. Then I use `onChange` to start my functions.

This is what I have so far, but it seems to return `false` in the console no matter which input I use.

```
function determineScope(element, scopeClass1, scopeClass2) {
  console.log('running');

  if (element.className.split(' ').indexOf(scopeClass1 || scopeClass2) >= 0) {

    if (scopeClass1) {
      console.log('put me in three obj');
    } else {
      console.log('put me in three arr');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can get this to check more than just the immediate `parentNode`?

**[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/31xdmgf8/)**

Comment: Try `if (element.closest('.three-obj') || element.closest('.three-array')) { }`

Comment: `element.classList.contains(someclass)`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes this works, but only for the first scope class. I tried to enter it in as `if (element.closest('.'+scopeClass1) || element.closest('.'+scopeClass2)) {` but could only get it to trigger the "put me in three-obj console.log. Here is my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31xdmgf8/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse the DOM tree top-down, using `querySelector` twice: once with `.three-obj`, and again with `.three-array`.

A space between parts of a selector indicates “*somwhere beneath*”, so `.three-obj [your-input-selector]` finds all elements which match `[your-input-selector]` that are somewhere inside one that matches `.three-obj`.

```js
const inputSelector = '...';

document.querySelector('.three-obj ' + inputSelector).forEach(elem => {
  console.log('Adding to three obj', elem);
});

document.querySelector('.three-array ' + inputSelector).forEach(elem => {
  console.log('Adding to three array', elem);
});
```

---

**Update:** From your linked fiddle, it appears you’ve misinterpreted my code. Does this snippet explain it better?

```js
function handleChange(type) {
  console.log('Change!', type, this);
}

const inputSelector = '.inputColor';

document.querySelectorAll('.three-obj ' + inputSelector).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => handleChange.bind(e.target)('obj'));
});

document.querySelectorAll('.three-arr ' + inputSelector).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => handleChange.bind(e.target)('arr'));
});
```

```html
<div class="three-obj">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="one">
      <label for="thing">thing1</label>
      <input class="inputColor" type="text" name="thing" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="three-arr">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="one">
      <label for="thing2">thing2</label>
      <input class="inputColor" type="text" name="thing2" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here’s a slightly more versatile method using data attributes:

```js
function handleChange() {
  const type = this.dataset.type;
  console.log('Change!', type, this);
}

const inputSelector = '.inputColor';

document.querySelectorAll('.three-obj ' + inputSelector).forEach(input => {
  input.dataset.type = 'obj';
});

document.querySelectorAll('.three-arr ' + inputSelector).forEach(input => {
  input.dataset.type = 'arr';
});

// getElementsByClassName is more efficient than querySelector
// However, it returns an HTMLCollection, not a NodeList
// This bizarre call allows you to use Array’s forEach function on it
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('inputColor'), input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => handleChange.bind(e.target)());
});
```

```html
<div class="three-obj">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="one">
      <label for="thing">thing1</label>
      <input class="inputColor" type="text" name="thing" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="three-arr">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="one">
      <label for="thing2">thing2</label>
      <input class="inputColor" type="text" name="thing2" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried setting a solution up utilizing this, but it seems to fire both console logs, even with the separate parsing. Any thoughts? [Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31xdmgf8/4/)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this! I originally learned with jquery, so trying to do it all in vanilla is a little tricky to understand sometimes. I wonder if it's worth it to query twice like this though? I kind of like how I originally query the all inputs, then just look for my change. I wonder if this would be a lot easier to just drop a data-attr on my inputs, then read that as my conditional?

Comment: That would work too, but you’d still need both selectors to set up the data attributes in the first place. The only difference would be that instead of getting the type passed in the event handler, it would be attached to the element itself. If you’re going to have more than one event handler on each element, this may well be a more useful solution for you.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since it does answer my original question, but after diving into the data attribute route, I kind of like it a little more since I can pass my attr values in a params into my main function. This utilizes a `data-attr` of `scope`. [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31xdmgf8/8/). Thanks for all the help looking into this! :)